# Unable to get last message based on timestamp from a group of messages where name is passed as query string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a following message table

[image]

and following user table

[image]

if i enter A in the search box it should output all the name starting with A with the last message according to timestamp.

for eg: I am login with 5.So it must give result

> Ramesh   first message  2015-07-23 10:16:34 
>   Ashish   first message  2015-07-25 10:16:34

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT m.*, @rn := IF(u.id = @prevUserId, @rn+1, 1) rn,@prevUserId := u.id FROM login u JOIN message m ON u.id IN (m.sender_id,m.receiver_id) WHERE u.name LIKE '%Abhishek%' ORDER BY u.id, timestamp desc) t1 WHERE rn = 1`

Comment: need to see the query

Comment: i'm using following query but it returns all rows where id is of Abhishek

Comment: Alright, we want to see it still.

Comment: Why are all messages 'first', and why are they all sent at exactly the same time? And what is the PRIMARY KEY ?

Comment: This is only sample and primary key is id.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it weel, you need a query that returns all of the users starts with "a" and have a conversation with the logged in user. I wrote this query for you:

```
SELECT 

  users_sender.`name` sender,
  m.message,
  m.`timestamp`

FROM `messages` m

LEFT JOIN `users` users_sender
  ON users_sender.id = m.sender_id
LEFT JOIN `users` users_receiver
  ON users_receiver.id = m.receiver_id

WHERE (users_sender.`name` LIKE "a%"
OR users_receiver.`name` LIKE "a%")

AND (users_sender.id = 5
OR users_receiver.id = 5)

ORDER BY m.`timestamp` DESC
```

It gives a result:

Ashish    first message   2015-07-25 10:16:34

Ramesh    first message   2015-07-22 10:16:34

Ramesh    first message   2015-07-23 10:16:34

According to your question you need every conversation that has the user 5 in its participants, so the example result is wrong, cause it gives you 2 rows, but according to your example database it needs to return 3 rows, as my query.

And please don't use unnecessary sub selects. As you can see you can solve this problem with joins. Comment if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks martin for your answer, but the query should return only the last conversation held between the user logged in and the other one so it must return Ramesh first message 2015-07-23 10:16:34 and Ashish first message 2015-07-25 10:16:34. Please update your answer.

Comment: Okay then it' way more easier to add a new flag field to your messages table called "is_readed", it's a tinyint(1) with default value 0, and add a WHERE to my query: "WHERE is_readed = 0", so it returns the unreaded messages only. And after this query you have to update these rows' is_readed field to 1. So these are flagged now as readed, and the next query won't return these,